# Is it possible to set the height of a div to the container minus the height of another div using css only?

Tags: css

Say I have a sticky footer div "with id #footer" at the bottom with height: 500px that floats above all content.

I have a div "with id #remaining" that i want to take up the whole height of the remaining page (but I do not want to "go under" the sticky footer. Is there a way in CSS3 to do something along the lines of:

```
#remaining {
height:100% - heightOf(#footer) // pseudocode
}
```

Am hoping I can avoid any javascript if its at all possible.

Comment: i think you're looking for `calc`

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the content of `#remaining` is greater than the height of the page minus the footer height? Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can provide a more succinct answer.

Comment: #remaining { height: calc(100% - 500px); } will give you a percentage

Comment: It depends no how the actual markup looks like, so show us that

Comment: @Gerard that should work, though is there a way for me to include a reference to a classname or specific id to automatically get the height of that instead of hardcoding 500px?

Comment: @Rolando No, you need a value

Comment: @Rolando... not when using CSS only

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use Flexbox? ... With that the _footer's_ height can be unknown

Comment: @LGSon I was just about to write the same comment

Comment: This simple sample shows how that can look like: https://jsfiddle.net/hxtLbfne/ ... and it will scale on all types of devices and screen sizes. To have 1 element adjust based on another, this is the modern (and better) way

Comment: Oooops...missed the scrollbar in previous sample: https://jsfiddle.net/hxtLbfne/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses `calc()` and [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) (an experimental feature) to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

:root {
  --footer-height: 150px;
}

.body {
  height: calc( 100% - var(--footer-height));
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.footer {
  height: var(--footer-height);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

We create a variable called `--footer-height`, and use it to set the height of `.footer`:

```
.footer {
  height: var(--footer-height);
```

We then use `calc` and `--footer-height` to set the height of `.body`:

```
.body {
  height: calc( 100% - var(--footer-height));
```

`box-sizing: border-box` allows us to add borders without increasing the height of the divs beyond 100% of the screen (more info [here](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/))

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calc()`:

`height: calc( 100vh - 500px );`

Though this may change depending on the markup.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  height: calc( 100vh - 200px );
  background-color: indianred;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

**Setting the height relative to the remaining space of the viewport might be undesirable on smaller viewports.*